# KnockoutJS - possible to use parent / child view models for SPA?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to know if KnockoutJS can support an application structured such that there is a main container div has been bound with applyBindings to a certain view model, and then have a child div inside of that div which has its own view model, but that they are able to communicate with one another?

```
 <div id="main">
   <div id="child">

   </div>
 </div>
```

then

```
ko.applyBindings(pageViewModel, document.getElementById('main'));
ko.applyBindings(childViewModel, document.getElementById('child'));
```

But then have some element within "child" be able to call a function that exists on the pageViewModel instead of childViewModel?  I feel like without this functionality, Knockout probably doesn't have support for a full fledged spa setup.  Is this in fact possible in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
ko.components.register('message-editor', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.clickFn = params.clickFunction
  },
  template: '<button data-bind="click:clickFn">Click</button>'
});

vm = {
  fn: function() {
    console.debug("Doing something in the parent");
  },
  fn2: function() {
    console.debug("Also something in the parent");
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h4>First instance, without parameters</h4>
<div data-bind='component: {
                name: "message-editor",
                params: {clickFunction: fn}
                }'></div>

<h4>Second instance, passing parameters</h4>
<div data-bind='component: {
    name: "message-editor",
    params: { clickFunction: fn2 }
}'></div>
```

Yes, you are looking for [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html). The master view model can bring in any number of components and pass them values for their view models, including observables or functions that operate on the master view model.

Comment: I have not used components in such a way before, so I am seeking an example of being able to "pass them functions that can operate on the master view model"

Comment: @mls3590712 I've added a simple example.